# How to open saved Location using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build an application, where I have 4 Locations for 4 Different stores, `If store 1` is clicked then `google map's` application should open with my `current location` and store 1 as `destination`,

How Can i achieve that, can someone share any relevant tutorial link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply launch the Google Maps URL.

You need this Flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Follow this documentation to get the URL: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action

This will look something like:

```dart
// See the above link to figure out what YOUR_OTHER_PARAMETERS should be
final url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&YOUR_OTHER_PARAMETERS';
launchUrl(
  Uri.parse(url),
  mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
);
```